# Python 'long' type is not iterable

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

So I am basically using a python function to collect data from a MySQL DB instance in AWS RDS, the connection to database is successfully however whenever the function below is called it returns an error

> 'long' type is not iterable.

```
def getLastData():
    for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM weather ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"):
        time = str(row[1])
        temp = row[2]
        hum = row[3]
        press = row[4]

    return time, temp, hum, press
```

heres how the **weather** table looks like

```
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| timestamp   | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| temperature | double     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| humidity    | double     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pressure    | double     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| not_raining | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am wondering what wrong with my code, any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the type of `row`? the way your code is accessing, it should be a list

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to the question.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: Why are you using a loop when the query only returns 1 row?

Comment: the line "for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM weather ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"):"

Answer (score 0):

You aren't quite using cursor objects correctly.

To execute a query, call the `execute()` method and then either iterate over the cursor or call various methods on it such as `fetchone()` or `fetchmany()`.  The return value of `cur.execute()` isn't something you can iterate over.

To change your code to iterate over the cursor, call `cur.execute(...)` on one line and then iterate over the cursor on the next:

```
def getLastData():
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM weather ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")
    for row in cur:
        time = str(row[1])
        temp = row[2]
        hum = row[3]
        press = row[4]

    return time, temp, hum, press
```

However, while this will appear to work as long as there is some weather data in the table, it will fail with a `NameError` if this table is empty, because there will be no rows to iterate over and hence the variables `time`, `temp` , `hum` and `press` will be undefined.

It would be better to call `cur.fetchone()` since we are expecting at most one row.  This will return the row of data if there is some data to read, or `None` if not.  We can then handle the error situation as necessary:

```
def getLastData():
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM weather ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        # TODO change this if necessary
        raise ValueError("No weather data found")
    else:
        time = str(row[1])
        temp = row[2]
        hum = row[3]
        press = row[4]

        return time, temp, hum, press
```

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.execute()` only returns an iterator if you supply the `multi=True` option.

```
for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM weather ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1", multi=True):
```

See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).